# How do I access and change the @environment variable in another struct?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In view `A` I use `.fullScreenCover()` to open  a full screen view `B`. And in this full screen view `B` there is a view named `C`, which has AVPlayer and some progress bar controls. I will also put some other views in view `B`.

So the question is, can I put a button in view `C` that closes the view `B`?

```
...

func listDir( a1:UTType = UTType.movie) -> Array<URL> {
    var directoryContents = [URL]()
    var directoryContentsW = [URL]()
    let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    directoryContentsW = try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
    
    for i in directoryContentsW{
        
        let ext_path = i.pathExtension.lowercased()
        if ext_path == "mp4" || ext_path == "mov" {
            directoryContents.append(i)
        }
        print("\(i.lastPathComponent): \(i.pathExtension)")

    }

    return directoryContents
}

struct Item: Identifiable{
    let posi: URL
    let id = UUID()
}

struct view_A: View {
    @State var item: Item? = nil
    @State var list0 = listDir()
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(list0, id: \.self){ i in
                Button( (i.lastPathComponent as NSString).deletingPathExtension ){
                    item = Item(posi: i)
                }
            }
        }.fullScreenCover(item: $item ,content: { view_B(item: $0) })
    }
}

struct view_B: View{
    let item: Item? = nil
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View{
        Color.primary.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        ZStack{
            view_C_videoPlay(filePosi: item!.posi)
        }
    }
}

struct view_C_videoPlay: View {
    @State var player: AVPlayer
    ...
    init(filePosi: URL){
        ...
    }
    var body: some View {
        Button("abc"){
        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

The compiler prompt:

```
Cannot find 'presentationMode' in scope
```

Comment: You don't need `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode` in `view_B`, move it into `view_C...`

Comment: So what if I put this button in another view to close the full screen view?

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use presentationMode just make a block var and in the implementation set item to nil. Call the block from a button handler. Repeat the pattern in each View to chain them up.

```
.fullScreenCover(item: $item) { i in 
    view_B(item: i) { result in
         // could do something with result
         item = nil
    }
```

Note if you don’t need the result there is a built in dismiss environment action you could try.

```
struct SheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            SheetContents()
                .toolbar {
                    Button("Done") {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```